# How to get the right hand side

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, special-functions

I am confused with how to get from $$\frac{x}{e^{x}-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B_{n}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$

In the book im studying from it says its a definition but idk how to generate terms from the right hand side or anything. I guess i should expand the left side in a series but idk what to do really. Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm somewhat confused as to what you're asking, but this is the [exponential generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function_(EGF)) for the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

Comment: I know what a generating function is. I have dealt with laguerre, legendre, jacobi and so on polynomials. Its just that there i have had how the $L_{n}$ looks for example and a left side for me to mess with in order to arrive at the right side. Idk what does even $B_{n}$ stand for here.

Comment: $B_n$ is the $n$th Bernoulli number.

Comment: Idk how would i go on about generating any term from the right side

Comment: Idk how are they defined

Comment: They are defined like that...

Comment: I believe you can take the $k$th derivative of both sides, and evaluate each at $x=0$. On the right-hand side, you'll have a single term which is a multiple of $B_k$. On the left-hand side, you'll have something else. Solve for $B_k$.

Comment: By multiplying the RHS by the denominator of the LHS, and equating the coefficients with the numerator (all zero except for the power $x$) you can obtain a recurrence relation.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the definition of $(B_n)_{n\geqslant 0}$ is the relation $\displaystyle\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{B_n}{n!}x^n$. Therefore
$$ x=\frac{x}{e^x-1}(e^x-1)=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{B_n}{n!}x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{B_k}{k!(n-k)!}\right)x^n $$
Thus $B_0=1$ and for all $n\geqslant 1$,
$$ B_n=-n!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{B_k}{k!(n-k+1)!}=-\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n+1}{k}B_k $$
This recursive relation makes it possible to compute the Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: Perhaps explain that "Thus $B_0=1$" follows (and the other partial sums are all 0) because we are equating coefficients of two polynomials, as Peanut's comment mentions.